# Word Math formatting

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting

I'm unsure of the correct terminology so I will have to use images to describe what I am after. If I have an equation with multiple steps, I want to format it to keep the equation in line over multiple lines.

So instead of this;

[image]

I want this;

[image]

Its hard to tell from the screenshots but I want the equals signs to line up with each other instead of starting from the beginning of the line again. I have tried moving the tabs on the ruler but cannot get them to line up and I am sure there is a way to get Word to format it properly anyways (sure I've seen it somewhere before).

At the moment I am just starting a new line/para and entering a new equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little help from @bibadia's answer, I have managed to sort it.

I found a good link [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Typing_Mathematics_in_Microsoft_Word#Multiple_Aligned_Equations)

Basically, the `\eqarray` starts an array of equations you may want to line up. All the equations you want to line up must be within parenthesis. Use the `@` symbol to separate equations (effectively a line break in this example) and the `&` symbol is located in front of whatever you want to line up (therefore I guess there must be the same number of ampersands in each equation, I haven't tested it).

So what I actually ended up using for my example is; `\eqarray(x&=W-Wa/L@&=WL-Wa/L)` as I only wanted them to line up from the `=` sign.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think there’s a simple way, or any good way, for this in Word. I would be happy to be wrong, but it seems that the best you can do is to set up a 2 by 2 table (using the normal Insert → Table in Word, not Equation Tools), write “x” in the first cell, leave the cell below it empty, and put the rest in the other cells. Then set horizontal alignment to left in the cells and vertical alignment to middle. Tuning spacing in cells a bit, you might end up with this (magnified here for clarity):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create your equation, then paste in the following and press Enter at the end:

```
\eqarray(&x&=&W-Wa/L @& &=&(WL-Wa)/L )
```

Comment: If I strip out the "&" and "@" characters, I see `x=W-Wa/L =(WL-Wa)/L` in your answer, so I guess it is an answer to ***this specific example***. Could you generalize your answer, so it can be used on other equations, and, while you're at it, explain what it does and how it works?

Comment: Have a look at http://www.unicode.org/notes/tn28/UTN28-PlainTextMath-v3.pdf section 3.19 (not everything in that document is available in the equation editor in Word)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @G-Man: I understand your comments, but I believe that an answer that correctly addresses the question as to whether such alignment is possible, correctly formats the sample equation given in the question, and which is enough to allow the reader to experiment and search for themselves should not be regarded as "The answer is not useful", particular when another arguably wrong answer has been posted. The conversation you reference may discuss the nature of a "good answer," but is actually about answers that consist merely of links, which this wasn't.